# Get a certain part of the project name in QGIS print composer label field?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression

E.g. my project is named `XXXX_YY_PRZZZ`. Is there a way for me to get only the `ZZZ` part for my label field? Maybe with `@project_basename` or some variables like that?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Hint look at `replace` under string expressions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
substr( @project_basename, strpos( @project_basename, '_PR' ) + 3 )
```

I assume string `_PR` exists in the project name.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it does.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz okay, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 6):

```
right(@project_basename,3)
```

could be an option